# Microsoft word `product(left)` for all numeric cells

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a table

[image]

The `Total Price` column has the formula `=product(left)`. However, the result is just the `Unit Price`. Can I force it to take the product of all numeric cells in the row?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PRODUCT field, you could use a formula (like Excel).  Assuming that your headings are part of the table (ie row 1 but with borders removed), the following formula will work copied into each cell of the Total Price column.

[image]

The formula is A2 * D2 for the first calculation, A3 * D3 for the second item.  The column references A and D are the same in each formula.

However, we want the row number to increase by 1.  We can use a SEQ field to do that automatically (ie not having to manually type formulas and edit if we add/delete rows).  The * Arabic switch is so we get number eg 1.

However, we don't want the row to increase again for the D part so the \c added to the SEQ field just returns the last SEQ value ie the increased row count value we had at A.

The QUOTE field is necessary so that Word will correctly interpret the A and SEQ as A2 for calculation - if you just had the A and SEQ field (ie not inside a QUOTE field), your calculation would return an error.

Below is a screenshot of the table with this field copied into the relevant cells of the Total column.  The total at bottom of column is just =SUM(ABOVE) field.
[image]

To update values in the total column, just select all and press F9 to update fields.

Comment: This is not working for me on MS Word for Mac 2019. Word does not see it as a formula and I can't toggle or update. I tried also removing the outermost brackets so '=' was first.