# Word 365 table formula relative to row value

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table in Word which does not contain a fixed number of rows.  We need to calculate values on each row and have the formulas added automatically to any additional rows inserted in to the table.  We can't embed Excel file before anyone asks, or macro-enabled.  Users won't be able to insert the formulas themselves either.

I can get this working by hard-coding formulas pasted on to each row.  But this won't work if more rows need adding.

I read other posts that said to use the SEQ operator but I can't get this working - e.g. below to multiply C2 by B2:

{ = { QUOTE "C{ = 1+{ SEQ row * Arabic} * Arabic }" }*{QUOTE "B{ = 1+{ SEQ row \c * Arabic} * Arabic }" } }

Screen shot below suggests the formula has taken but nothing happens.  If I can crack the yellow cell then I can sort the rest.

Thanks!

[Table in Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXL8M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one extra pair of brackets for your formatting, but they're breaking the calculation. Try this:

```
{ = { QUOTE "C{ = 1+{ SEQ row \* Arabic } }" }*{ QUOTE "B{ = 1+{SEQ row \c \* Arabic } }" } \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)" }
```

---

Explanation from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1133435/microsoft-word-productleft-for-all-numeric-cells), though their screenshot has a typo:

> The formula is A2 * D2 for the first calculation, A3 * D3 for the second item. The column references A and D are the same in each formula.
>
> However, we want the row number to increase by 1. We can use a SEQ field to do that automatically (ie not having to manually type formulas and edit if we add/delete rows). The * Arabic switch is so we get number eg 1.
>
> However, we want the row number to increase by 1. We can use a SEQ field to However, we don't want the row to increase again for the D part so the \c added to the SEQ field just returns the last SEQ value ie the increased row count value we had at A.
>
> However, we want the row number to increase by 1. We can use a SEQ field to The QUOTE field is necessary so that Word will correctly interpret the A and SEQ as A2 for calculation - if you just had the A and SEQ field (ie not inside a QUOTE field), your calculation would return an error.

If it's not working for you, try and do these one at a time:

```
{ = A2*B2 \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)"}
{ = { QUOTE "A2" }*{ QUOTE "B2" } }
{ = { QUOTE "A{ = 1+1 }" }*{ QUOTE "B{ = 1+1 }" } }
{ = { QUOTE "A{ = 1+{ SEQ row \* Arabic } }" }*{ QUOTE "B{ = 1+{SEQ row \c \* Arabic } }" } }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd seen that post also which led me to thinking I was doing something wrong somewhere. The only one of your suggestions that works is { = B2*C2 \# "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)"}.  I enter it into the Formula box without the outer most curly brackets.  All of the others return a "!Syntax Error, {" message, again without the outer most brackets.  If I paste the full formula as above with the outer most brackets it adds another pair and a blank result in the cell.  Anything else I can try?

Comment: @Blinky73 you cannot paste the full formula as text - each pair of curly brackets has to be inserted since they're separate formulas. After you type it in once manually, then you can copy the cell to other cells

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale but I must be missing something obvious!  Are you saying I can't paste the formula directly into the Formula box (Layout menu > Formula with the table selected).  That's what I've been trying with and without the outer brackets. How do I insert the curly brackets?

Comment: @Blinky73 Press `Ctrl+F9` to insert formula brackets. It inserts open+close together (and they're not movable), so it may be helpful to insert all the pairs first, like `{ {{{}}}*{{{}}} }`, then type in the rest of the formula. The brackets don't actually exist as text. They are technically Field objects, so you can only copy and paste them within word. Other shortcuts are `F9` to run the whole thing, and `Shift+F9` to show/hide the formulas (same as right-click > toggle field codes). You'll notice that `Shift+F9` only reveals one field (pair of brackets) at a time

Comment: Note: You only have to do it as nested fields because you need word to process the row number before it does the rest of the calculations

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  Thanks for your help @Cpt.Whale.